# PHP SoapServer classmap object creation

Tags: php, soapserver

I am building a web service with PHP's SoapServer class. Using the **classmap** feature works fine and the WSDL types are correctly mapped to the PHP types. However, I am not able to figure out how the instances of the mapped classes are created.

Is there any way to effect the creation of the object generated by the SoapServer? For example something like the __set_state magic method.

Example: I am using the xsd tytes date and datetime respectively. I want to ensure that these are converted into PHP's DateTime classes. What I do not want do to is have a downstream process which does that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the proper way of doing that is the **typemap** option for SoapServer. Eg,

```
$options = array (
    'typemap' => array (
        array(
            'type_name' => 'XMLNodeForMyClass',
            'type_ns' => 'urn:localurn',
            'from_xml' => 'MyClass::fromSOAP',
            'to_xml' => 'MyClass::toSOAP'
        )
    )
);
```

---

```
class MyClass {
    static public function fromSOAP( string $xml ) {}
    static public function toSOAP( MyClass $Outgoing ) {}
}
```